# Stacking a new element on the original page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking for a solution to stacking a new element on the top of original page using javascript.

More detailed, I want to render a grid on the top of the original web page.

[image: The effect I want]

I have tried to use canvas to render the grid and use format them by css, but it will mess up the page.

```js
console.log('injecting...')

document.body.innerHTML += '<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>'

document.getElementById('wrapper').style = 'position: absolute'
document.getElementById('myCanvas').style = 'position: absolute'

eventWindowLoaded()

function eventWindowLoaded() {
    canvasApp();
}
function canvasSupport(e) {

    return !!e.getContext;

}
function canvasApp() {
    var myCanvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

    if (!canvasSupport(myCanvas)) {
        return;
    }

    var ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');

    myCanvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    myCanvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    function drawScreen() {

        var dx = 50;
        var dy = 50;


        var x = 0;
        var y = 0;
        var w = myCanvas.width;
        var h = myCanvas.height;



        var xy = 10;

        ctx.lineWidth = 1;

        while (y < h) {
            y = y + dy;
            ctx.moveTo(x, y);
            ctx.lineTo(w, y);
            ctx.stroke();


            ctx.font = "1px Calibri";
            ctx.fillText(xy, x, y);
            xy += 10;
        }


        y = 0;
        xy = 10;
        while (x < w) {
            x = x + dx;
            ctx.moveTo(x, y);
            ctx.lineTo(x, h);
            ctx.stroke();

            ctx.font = "1px Calibri";
            ctx.fillText(xy, x, 10);
            xy += 10;
        }
    }

    drawScreen();

}
```

Is there a solution that will work on all the pages?

Comment: Why don't you just use a grid pattern as background image of your web page?

Comment: > "I have tried to use canvas to render the grid and use format them by css, but it will mess up the page." - I guess with some css it would be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Using `z-index` css attribute, and put `top` and `left` position absolute to **0**.
- Set the `width` and `height` attribute to **100%** in order to fill all the page.

```js
console.log('injecting...')

document.body.innerHTML += '<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>';

document.getElementById('wrapper').style = 'position: absolute';
document.getElementById('myCanvas').style = 'position: absolute';

eventWindowLoaded()

function eventWindowLoaded() {
    canvasApp();
}
function canvasSupport(e) {

    return !!e.getContext;

}
function canvasApp() {
    var myCanvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

    if (!canvasSupport(myCanvas)) {
        return;
    }

    var ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');

    myCanvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    myCanvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    function drawScreen() {

        var dx = 50;
        var dy = 50;


        var x = 0;
        var y = 0;
        var w = myCanvas.width;
        var h = myCanvas.height;



        var xy = 10;

        ctx.lineWidth = 1;

        while (y < h) {
            y = y + dy;
            ctx.moveTo(x, y);
            ctx.lineTo(w, y);
            ctx.stroke();


            ctx.font = "1px Calibri";
            ctx.fillText(xy, x, y);
            xy += 10;
        }


        y = 0;
        xy = 10;
        while (x < w) {
            x = x + dx;
            ctx.moveTo(x, y);
            ctx.lineTo(x, h);
            ctx.stroke();

            ctx.font = "1px Calibri";
            ctx.fillText(xy, x, 10);
            xy += 10;
        }
    }

    drawScreen();

}
```

```css
canvas {
  z: index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"><div>
```

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/z-index.

Answer (score 0):

Inject an absolute positioned element directly into the body with high `z-index` and use [CSS grid layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) for the grid system.